# Number Format Current Culture

Tags: c#, internationalization, format

I was trying to get the number format in order to convert from string to decimal using the current culture, I have the next configuration in my system:

[image]

I would like use the current culture info, but using the customize format like the decimal symbol, digit grouping symbol, etc.

Is it there a way to recover the customize format configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> Windows allows users to override the standard property values of the
>   CultureInfo object and its associated objects by using Regional and
>   Language Options in Control Panel. The CultureInfo object returned by
>   the CurrentCulture property reflects these user overrides in the
>   following cases:

- If the current thread culture is set implicitly by the Windows
  GetUserDefaultLocaleName function.
- If the current thread culture
  defined by the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture property corresponds to
  the current Windows system culture.
- If the current thread culture is
  set explicitly to a culture returned by the CreateSpecificCulture
  method, and that culture corresponds to the current Windows system
  culture.
- If the current thread culture is set explicitly to a culture
  instantiated by the CultureInfo(String) constructor, and that culture
  corresponds to the current Windows system culture.

When you pass CurrentCulture, it will be used to pass the string to a decimal.

```
decimal number;
if (!decimal.TryParse(numberString, NumberStyles.Number, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out number))
{
    // Something wrong...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take current Culture Number Format from the `CurrentThread`.

```
var format = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat;
```

**EDIT:**

[**CultureInfo.NumberFormat**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.numberformat(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The user might choose to override some of the values associated with
>   the current culture of Windows through the regional and language
>   options portion of Control Panel. For example, the user might choose
>   to display the date in a different format or to use a currency other
>   than the default for the culture.
>
> If UseUserOverride is true and the
>   specified culture matches the current culture of Windows, the
>   CultureInfo uses those overrides, including user settings for the
>   properties of the DateTimeFormatInfo instance returned by the
>   DateTimeFormat property, and the properties of the NumberFormatInfo
>   instance returned by the NumberFormat property. If the user settings
>   are incompatible with the culture associated with the CultureInfo, for
>   example, if the selected calendar is not one of the OptionalCalendars,
>   the results of the methods and the values of the properties are
>   undefined.

So `var decimalDigits = format.NumberDecimalDigits;` should return your custom changes.

Comment: Close, but the problem is recover the customized format for the current culture.

Comment: @GonzaloAguayo check the edit. Check if UseUserOverride is true.